# Load single byte to texture in LWJGL/LibGDX

Tags: libgdx, lwjgl

I have a luminance map in LibGDX. I use a ByteBuffer to load my pixels, which works fine.

```
    Gdx.graphics.getGL20().glPixelStorei(GL20.GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
    Gdx.graphics.getGL20().glTexImage2D(GL20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL20.GL_LUMINANCE, overviewBlock.getWidth(), overviewBlock.getHeight(), 0,
            GL20.GL_LUMINANCE,
            GL20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, overviewBuffer);
```

However, I have trouble understanding how bytes are translated to the floats in GLSL. For a color based on an integer, writing to the ByteBuffer works like a charm. But I am not sure how to do this with a single byte color.

```
                    buffer.put((byte)255);
```

This does not result in a 1.0 value in GLSL/OpenGL, if I'm not mistaken. What is the correct way to get values in GLSL between 0 and 1.0, from say an integer ranged 0 - 255?

Comment: A `byte` in Java is signed from the range [**-128**, **127**]. **255** is not in that range (**-1** is actually what you would need), you will have one heck of a time getting that constant to represent **1.0**. You might consider promotion to integer: `buffer.put ((byte)(255 & 0xff));` That promotes 255 to an integer, masks only the low 8-bits and then casts it back to `byte`. Then you really do not have to care what the range of a `byte` is, because that constant is treated as a signed integer instead; the sign-bit in a signed integer is well outside the lowest-order 8-bits so that helps.

Comment: Actually, come to think of it, that should only apply to ***reading*** an "unsigned" byte, not so much writing one.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Can't you just specify the byte in hex? `buffer.put((byte)0xff);` for 255. I haven't tested this, but it's what I'd try first.

Comment: Well, that suffers from the same problem - namely the 8th bit is a sign bit. The number **0xff** is actually **-1**. But since nobody is interpreting values here this really does not matter, my mind was working in reverse. Say you had an unsigned byte coming from OpenGL and then ***you*** wanted to do fixed-point -> floating-point conversion yourself, *then* the fact that **0xff** is interpreted as **-1** would matter. Here it really does not.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Your approach seems to work well as far as I can tell.  I don't quite understand yet why -128 is represented as 0x00 at the end bits, but that's my own ignorance on the subject. Either way I'm using (byte)(integer & 0xff) and 0xff for 255/1.0 in short and 0x00 for 0/0.0 in short. That part does make sense to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using buffer.write((byte)(integer number & 0xff)) to write my bytes as recommended per the comments.